# angular 2 testing mock service

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I am trying to mock out a service in my angular 2 test but it just keeps using the real one and giving me loads of errors related to not finding the dependencies of that service

here is my component file

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {ClientService} from '../client.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'registry',
    templateUrl: './registry.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './registry.component.scss'.toString()
   ]
})

export class RegistryComponent {    

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {
    }

    loadResources() {
        return this.clientService.getBusinessNetwork()
    }
}
```

And this my test file

```
import {NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {inject, async, TestBed, ComponentFixture} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import * as sinon from 'sinon';

import {RegistryComponent} from './registry.component';
import {ClientService} from '../client.service';

describe(`Registry`, () => {
   let comp: RegistryComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<RegistryComponent>;

   beforeEach(() => {
       let MockClientService = {
           getBusinessNetwork : sinone.stub()
       };

       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           declarations: [RegistryComponent],
           schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
           providers: [
               {provide: ClientService, useValue: MockClientService},
           ]
       })
         .compileComponents(); // compile template and css
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegistryComponent);
      comp = fixture.componentInstance;

      fixture.detectChanges(); // trigger initial data binding
    });

    it('should have default data', () => {
        comp.should.be.true;
    });
});
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I can't reproduce error using your example. It works!))

Comment: Is it possible you have a `@Component.providers` you aren't showing us? That would cause the behavior you're describing. As an aside, `compileComponents` should be wrapped in `async`. Can you provide a [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview&show=app%2Fbanner-inline.component.spec.ts) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: No i don't have a `@Component.providers` I found the reason it doesn't work is that my service has a constructor, how do i mock the constructor?

Comment: The actual service constructor has nothing to do with anything, as the mock is being used. This means the actual service is never touched at all. It (the class) is simply used as a lookup token. The problem is elsewhere

Comment: If i comment out declarations in my constructor in the service it works and if i put them in it doesn't work

Comment: The point is that the real service constructor shouldn't even be involved. So the test is trying to create the real service. That's the problem. It should not be doing this.

Comment: [here's a template](https://plnkr.co/edit/D3S5E1lCrv3g3dR08mHY?p=preview). See if you can reproduce the problem

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the template, so the only thing i can think of then is that as i am using webpack i have some configuration wrong, i think it must be loading the dependencies before the test tells it to use the mock

Comment: May be it will be helpfull to monkey patch TestBed and detect who trying to load real service

```var originalFunction = coreTesting.TestBed.prototype.get;
    coreTesting.TestBed.prototype.get = function () {
      console.log(arguments);
      return originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    };```

Comment: Where do i put that? i put it in my `beforeEach` and nothing came out on the console, also tried it in my actual test

Comment: in [modified template](https://plnkr.co/edit/AcNF8HRIpRoqqO4obvIt?p=preview) i paste it after initTestEnvironment call